# Pawn giving checkmate

Tags: rules, pawns, checkmate, kings, en-passant

My computer checkmated me with a pawn move.

I could have taken that pawn en passant but I wasn't given a chance to do that.

Was that a fault of my computer, or is there a rule stating that a pawn giving checkmate cannot be taken en passant?

Answer (score 12):

I would love to see the position; please add it to your question somehow (we can always edit it to look nice). However, there is no such rule. Either your computer doesn't implement captures en passant (improbable these days) or the capture was not valid for some other reason.

Comment: On reflection it was played on my nintendo, not my computer, and I have no record of the position.

Comment: Maybe the computer cheated you. This a new phenomenon that has arisen with smarter engines :D

Comment: As for the "improbable these days" part... I know of current high volume "chess" implementations that don't even implement castling!

Answer (score 11):

Maybe your pawn happened to be pinned?

```
 8/8/7r/5K1k/7p/8/6P1/7R w - - 0 1

 1. g4+# hxg3?? 2. Rxh5
```

Comment: There cannot be moves after checkmate

Comment: Yes, of course; I was using "??" to indicate not a weak but an illegal move, with "2 Rxh5" explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, the *computer checkmated you* with a pawn move from the 2nd to the 4th rank. (Such a move is the only situation that invokes the en passant rule.)

Checkmate ends the game.  That is why you were not permitted to capture; the game is already over.

Comment: This misses the question, being if an ep-capture is allowed in that scenario (which of course it is). It just isn't checkmate if e.p. is a legal move.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the timing of events in your game (the question doesn't state that the e.p. capture should have been possible prior to the computer's move, or that the computer checkmated you by moving the same pawn again (the one that you were unable to capture e.p. on your prior move).  Is that the correct description of the events? I.e. 1. Computer advances a2-a4. 2. You attempt to capture b4xa3, but are not allowed to. 3. The computer advances a4-a5, giving checkmate. Is that it?

Comment: It's not my question, but I think it's like this: computer played a2-a4 and announced checkmate (although b4xe3 e.p. *might* have been possible). Without the game record impossible to answer for sure. But I've seen too many low quality mass-product "chess" apps that got the rules wrong that I wouldn't be surprised if it was a bug.

Comment: @Eiko OP needs to provide details of the chronology of events, it seems, since there is sufficient ambiguity in the account to make the question impossible to answer correctly with any certainty. I've offered 2 interpretations; the 2nd would require further details to determine why the move was disallowed.

Comment: I think the question is clearly saying that the computer played a2-a4 and said that it was checkmate, even though b4xa3 is possible. (Of course OP may be mistaken too and b4xa3 was illegal for some other reason)

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  If the pawn can legally be captured en passant, it is not checkmate, only check.  By your logic, it would be impossible to get out of check, because the game would end. For it to end the game, the en passant capture would have to be illegal for some other reason (a pin being the only one that springs to mind, since a double check isn't possible in this specific scenario).